# "You started taking revenge" is that correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which is correct between these two sentences?

> **A**: You started taking revenge.
>   **B**: You started take revenge.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is correct.  The second is not correct in its current form.  It would be correct to state:
"you started to take revenge"

The first version conveys the meaning of the revenge starting and continuing, the second (corrected form) only that it started.

Answer (score 0):

Also, note that the second one can be corrected if it is changed to "You started to take revenge."